# MatLab ismembertol function that does not allow elements to match with more than one other element

Tags: matlab, matrix, unique

I have two column matrices with an unequal number of rows.

Both column matrices (let us call them `T1` and `T2`) are a non-periodic set of unique integers sorted in increasing order.

`T1` and `T2` can be simulated by:

```
T1=sort(randperm(10E6,100)) ;
T1=T1';

T2=sort(randperm(10E6,100)) ;
T2=T2';
```

What I would like to do is to count unique matches of elements in the `T1` matrix with the elements of the `T2` matrix within a set tolerance.  That is to say, if an element in `T1` is matched with an element in `T2`, neither element can be matched with any other elements.

I know that `ismembertol` gives a logical value where the elements of `T1` are within tolerance of the elements in `T2`, however, the MathWorks' documentation does not specify if the found matches are unique or not.  From my own tests, it appears that they are not.

Is there a way to count such unique matches between two matrices?

Comment: Assume that `T1=[ 5 ;12];` and `T2=[ 6; 8];` and tolerance is 5. first 6 will match with 5 so no problem. Now 8 should not be matched with 5 but  should it be matched with 12 or should it be ignored?

Comment: @rahnema1 In this case the 8 of array `T2` should be ignored.

Comment: I undeleted my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your sentence

> "That is to say, if an element in T1 is matched with an element in T2,
>   neither element can be matched with any other elements"

it seems that you look for a 2 ways check, meaning that the ismember-ish tools don't seem fitted for you, as they have a direction.

I'll have to first put there a pseudo-version of checking equality within a tolerance :

```
 function out=isequaltol(a,b,tol)

if numel(a)>numel(b)

    out=zeros(size(a));

else

    out=zeros(size(b));

end

out(abs(a-b)<tol)=1;

end
```

**NOTE :** You DO need a vectorized function there, because although `bsxfun` is made to operates elementwise , it does vectorize operations to speed up the process.

Okay now you look for elements that are uniquely present in both `T1` and `T2` within a tolerance. The blockquote I put at the top of the answer suggests that you're looking for a two ways solution :

**NOTE :** As suggested in your example I'll suppose that `T1` and `T2` are column vectors

```
T1=sort(randperm(100,10)) ;
T1=T1';

T2=sort(randperm(100,10)) ;
T2=T2';

% define tolerance
tol=10;

% Create function handle to equality within tol checking
fun=@(a,b) isequaltol(a,b,tol);

% Concatenate all values in T1 and T2
All_values=sort([T1;T2]);

% Check for equality within tolerance between All_values and itself using bsxfun and its singleton expansion:
TmpOut=bsxfun(fun,All_values,All_values.');

% Discard diagonal values as they are 1 for sure
TmpOut2=TmpOut-diag(diag(TmpOut));

% Now you're looking for rows that have one and only one 1 in them
Out=All_values(sum(TmpOut2,2)==1);

% If you want to get the count of such values :
Count=numel(Out);

% If you want to retrieve the value that come from T1 (resp. T2)
Out_From_T1=Out(ismember(Out,T1));
Out_From_T2=Out(ismember(Out,T2));
```

### SAMPLE RUN

```
T1 =

     4
     7
    31
    38
    50
    61
    63
    70
    75
   100

T2 =

     9
    11
    25
    32
    40
    53
    59
    72
    74
    96

Out =

    96
   100
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `interp1` function to find nearest matches of `T1` to `T2` and assign corresponding elements, value of `T2`.
So if `T1 = [ 1; 5; 15; 18]` and `T2=[ 2; 3; 6; 50];` then `out` will be `out = [1 5 5 18];` that means first element of `T2` matches with the first element of `T1` and second and third elements of `T2` match with second element of `T1` and fourth element of `T2` matches with fourth element of `T1`. So we have two elemets of `T2` that matches with the same element from `T1` that we need to remove (neglect) the element(s) that has greater distance to element of `T1`. For it elements first sorted based on their distance and indices of the first unique elements extracted. Finally `result` is the count of the same elements within the desired tolerance `tol`.

```
out = interp1(T1, T1,T2, 'nearest', 'extrap');
DIST = abs(out - T2);
[~,IS] = sortrows([out DIST]);
[~,IU] = unique(out(IS) ,'first');
result = sum(DIST(IS(IU)) < tol);
```